How to sum up multiple VLOOKUP results?
I've got two lists: one with items and one with orders



Item
Price




1
10.10


2
2.02






Order
Item 1
Item 2
...
Item 15
Sum




A
1



10.10


B
1
2


12.12



For each order I want to sum up the prices of the items listed in that row (see last column).
I've tried searching for a formula but everything I've found refers to a different problem. Either they want to sum up multiple columns of a single result or they want to look up multiple rows based on a single value. And I've not been able to adapt those formulas or ideas to my problem.

Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?

Thank you for not uploading images of code/data/errors.

Use MAP() then SUM(). Try-
=SUM(MAP(E2:H3,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A,B2:B,0))))


Edit: After comment by OP.

Try-
=BYROW(E2:H3,LAMBDA(r,SUM(MAP(r,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A,B2:B,0))))))

And full dynamic formula to refer all rows.
=BYROW(E2:H,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTIFS(r,">0")=0,,SUM(MAP(r,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A,B2:B,0)))))))



I don't want to sum up all orders. First row should sum up to 10.1 and the second to 12.12

@Kempeth Can you show you desired result on post.

I've added the information to the question.

@Kempeth How it is 12.12 as you only have one item matching for row two with price table. Can you please explain?

That was a typo. The second item on row two should have been a "2"

@Kempeth Then try =BYROW(E2:H3,LAMBDA(r,SUM(MAP(r,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A,B2:B,0)))))) See edited answer.

@Kempeth Full dynamic formula =BYROW(E2:H,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTIFS(r,">0")=0,,SUM(MAP(r,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A,B2:B,0))))))).
